# Physical device does not stay selected for deploys

Tags: c#, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to deploy my project on my physical device. I have done this many times before. For some reason, all of a sudden, I try to choose the physical device but after selecting my device it comes back to the emulator (1-2 secs after) without me touching anything.

Comment: I've seen this happen on a device when the device's battery is nearly dead. Your best bet is to unplug the device, restart VS, and try again once it's been charged a bit more.

Comment: Hmm ok, my device was at 90% so I do not think that is the issue. I tried what you suggested but no luck. Bummer...

Comment: Just to let you know you are not alone, I'm experiencing the exact same thing with Xamarin in VS2017 15.4. Option regularly resets to emulator, I (blindly) hit F5 to redeploy to device (live player on device), only to be greeted by an undesired and slow emulator startup.